# how to change the number of rendered frames in Blender

Tags: animation, rendering, blender

i´m using blender to render an animation in single pictures and i want to make an 16 frames animation out of an 24 frames one without changing the set keyframes. Is there an option to skip every 3rd frame and just render the rest? I only found the frame step option, which allows you to render every 3rd, but not 2 frames and skip the 3rd.
If anyone could help, thank you very much!

Comment: You want to remove frames and make the resulting animation choppy? Or you want to make the same animation play in less time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DopeSheet panel, select all the key frames that make up your 24 frames of animation. Then press `s` to enter scale mode. Scale the 24 frame animation to 16 frames.

Comment: @BlenderNewbie Great. You can also press `g` to grab frames and move them around if needed.